# Softmax dealing with non present classes

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, loss-functions, softmax

Is it okey to assume that, if I have trained my neural network for image classification using k classes using a Softmax output function, whenever I feed an image that does not belong to any of the k classes used for training, the output of the Softmax will be the highest for the class that the network believes this new input is most similar to? Or how that would work?

Isn't it a big disadvantage of the Softmax function **when used for classification purposes (edited)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is ok to assume that. But most probably, the probabilty of all classes will be similar. (Depends on the input though).

No. This is not a disadvantage of the softmax function. Infact, it is just a 
function. I think you mean the way we use softmax in tasks like this.

Comment: Well yeah, I meant the use of the softmax function for classification purposes yes. But why do you say that the probability of all classes will be similar?

Comment: Your assumption is correct but that is not a disadvantage of softmax, but a design problem, since the network has to assume the input you feed into it is something supposed to be classified. You’d better include the all the “unexpected” classes in your design by having a class like “none of the rest”. Just like logistic regression, you usually have one class A, and the other class “not A”. Note the word “unexpected” is quoted because when you include those classes, they are expected, just not labelled as usual.

Comment: @sdiabr What I meant actually is, if your network has been trained to classify dogs, trees and cars, then if you show it a cat, it, most probably, will output the highest probability for the dog class. But if you network classifies dogs and cat, and I show it a wolf, then the network will output, most probably, a similar probability for both the classes.  I hope you see what I'm trying to indicate. If your network is show images beloging to classes which it hasn't been trained on, then the network will most naturally be confused and output what it thinks it belongs.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean @DibyaPrakashDas, I just did not agree with the statement "the probability of all classes will be similar. (Depends on the input though". It really depends on the input. 
I guess if I train a NN to classify cats and dogs, and then I input a picture of a tree, it would push up the probabilities of the class that the NN thinks the tree is more similar to, always adding up to 1 of course. 
Xiao-FengLi yeah that sounds reasonable.
Thanks for the comments